# How can I tell BCP to add headers to an output text file?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am running this code; it only return data, how can I get headers in my file?

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 
 'bcp "SELECT * FROM table1 " queryout G:\Backup\Test.txt -t"|" -c -T '
```

Comment: Why are you calling a command-line app from TSQL only for it to call back into TSQL? Why not just call it from a command-line in the first place?

Comment: @Charlieface Perhaps this is a scheduled process and they have preference of using SQL Agent Jobs. That would be one reason I could think of.

Comment: @J.D. Then use CmdExec jobs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-cmdexec-job-step?view=sql-server-ver16 `xp_cmdshell` just has no place in any decent code.

Comment: @J.D. To be honest I don't think `bcp.exe` should be used either. Powershell has better tools, such as `Invoke-SqlCmd` or `Invoke-DbaQuery` which you can feed directly to `Export-Csv`. You can write SQL Agent jobs in Powershell as well.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1355876/10592356

Answer (score 0):

> I am running this code:

[typical BCP query]

> only return data,how can I get headers in my file?

There's a few solutions to this problem. One simple way is to hard-code them with a `UNION ALL` query like so:

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell
'bcp 
"
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ''ColumnABC'') AS Column1, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ''ColumnDEF'') AS Column2, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ''ColumnGHI'') AS Column3 

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
    ColumnABC, 
    ColumnDEF, 
    ColumnGHI 
FROM table1
" queryout G:\Backup\Test.txt -t"|" -c -T '
```

Comment: EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell'bcp 
"SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "Database" AS Database, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "Customer/Account Number" AS Customer/Account Number, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), "Site Number" AS Site Number

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
     [Database], 
    [Customer/Account Number], 
    [Site Number]
FROM trux_ww_comp.dbo.CustomerInformation
" queryout G:\Backup\BankInfo.txt -t"|" -c -T '

Comment: @Yulichka You're using double quotes: `"Database"` when you should be using two single quotes instead `''Database''`.

Comment: I already tried that and it is not working, any other sugestions? Thank you so much

Comment: EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell'bcp 
"SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ''State'') AS State,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), ''Zip'') AS Zip 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 
     [State], 
    [Zip]

FROM trux_ww_comp.dbo.CustomerInformation
" queryout G:\Test.txt -t"|" -c -T '

Comment: @Yulichka No problem. What error are you getting?